# Are there Legal Requirements to inform EU immigration about other passports I might have?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, legal

Could I travel for example into Germany as a US citizen (= on an US passport), and *not* tell them that I am a French citizen too? Or this a violation?

Comment: Do you have a French passport? If so, it would make much more sense to enter Germany using that passport. As an EU citizen, your freedom of movement rights get you into Germany; as a US citizen, you have to convince Germany to let you in.

Answer (score 4):

If the passport you're using has a visa requirement, you would usually have to list any other nationalities (not just passports) on the application form. Making incomplete statements is a lie.

If the passport you're using has no visa requirement, you won't be asked.

As David pointed out in his comment, a French citizen (with or without passport) **cannot** get a visa for Germany. He has a right to enter with just his national ID card and to stay as long as he doesn't do anything to get himself deported. And getting deported would be extremely difficult, ordinary crimes or stupidity are not enough.